# Translating "be right back" (or "brb")

Tags: traducción

In informal spoken English, if we need to interrupt a conversation or meeting to take care of something else and then return, we might use expressions such as:

> - I'll be right back.
> - I'll be back in a minute.
> - Sorry, gimme one sec.

What is the best rendering of this phrase in Spanish?

Also, in online communication, it is common to type "brb" as an acronym for "be right back." Is there a similar *short form* used online in Spanish?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well there is only one way I know of that sounds both natural and short in Spanish for saying be right back.

> Ya vuelvo

I can't think of another way to say it. In case you want to say, I'll be back in a minute it would be:

> Vuelvo en X minuto(s)

And for "Sorry, gimme a sec":

> Espera, dame un segundo

As per comments it seems in Spain it is more common to use

> Ahora vuelvo

than "Ya vuelvo." This sounds quite natural to me as well:

> Vuelvo enseguida

This is correct too:

> Ya vengo

And finally, another common phrase:

> Vuelvo en un momento

Comment: You can also say "Ahora vuelvo" or "Vuelvo enseguida". Indeed I think they sound more natural than "ya vuelvo", at least in Spain.

Comment: "ya regreso" is also common (at least where I am), and has essentially an identical meaning.

Comment: In Chile you can say "Vuelvo al tiro"

Comment: What about "ya vengo"?

Comment: I use "vuelvo enseguida" - I think I asked a Mexican about this, so it's probably Mexican Spanish.

Comment: @jrdioko: Ya vengo is also widely used. In the end there are many many many ways to say that.

Answer (score 3):

> Regresaré pronto.
>
> Regresaré en un minuto.
>
> Perdón, dame un momento (*moment*).

or literally translated as

> Perdón, dame un segundo.

Comment: "Literally"? The first of those is the closest to a literal translation.

Answer (score -2):

"Esperte, ahorita vengo," means "wait, I'll be right there."  Not all things translate exactly.

Especially when it comes down to "indigenous sayings." An example of the way we speak in regards to sayings on the border, a typical conversation here in the Mexican barrios or hoods would go something like this if translated to Enlish:

> person no. 1 - what wave?....
>   person no. 2 - oranges, you?....
>   person no. 1 - nor potatoes!...

in Spanish it would be..

> Que onda?
>   Naranjas, y tu?
>   Ni papas!

Now THAT is a real conversation everyone in our hoods would understand immediately. But we speak our own brand of indigenous Spanish! Also saying "Ya mero hay voy" would roughly translate to "I'll be right there." Many different ways exist depending on the level of familiarity with each other.

Comment: -1 I don't think this answer is related to the OP's question

Comment: @Shaz Well, "ahorita vengo" is a valid answer: it is how many Mexicans would say it.  "Espérate", too, especially if it had been spelled correctly.  I agree that the rest is irrelevant.